# Predict time series using NN trained with multiple TS

Tags: time-series, rnn, prediction

I'm trying to predict time series using RNN from keras and I have several time series to work with (these are sales from some stores, just usual 1D TS).
  Right now I can train one simple model using one TS and then predict this one TS using this one model, so it is just one model for one series. But it is not effective and I need some way to train ONE model with all the time series I have and then to predict new time series using this model. 
I've read about multivariate time series but couldn't get it to work. Also I tried to aggregate the time series into one, but result of prediction wasn't good at all.
I am using keras with python3.